# Hyperledger Fabric Timed Transactions/Events

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

To my knowledge, there isn't a way to do timed transaction in Hyperledger Fabric.

Consider the use case using the marbles example. Say I want to transfer a marble 600 seconds after I received it. Does the Fabric SDK provide anyway for me to get the unix timestamp of the event when I received my marble then send another transaction to a queue that will happen exactly 600 seconds later by calculating the timestamp + 600?

Comment: Something similar was brought up by others in the past, but is it really a client side responsibility
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2002

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about the time when the Marbles are actually received, then in my opinion you have to write some code on both sides. i.e, both at client and the chaincode sides.

I am not sure how to do the same with only SDK/Client side code.

If you are willing to write something in your transaction processing logic, there is a method **ChaincodeStubInterface.GetTxTimestamp()** in the *github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim* package to get the time when the transaction is processed by the Fabric.

You could return the same to your SDK, and then to your external calling program. And then compute the +600 seconds and send the next transaction.

Comment: I am aware of the shim function, but you are saying it must be done on the client side then

Comment: May be you can do this in the chaincode itself too. Just get the time and when it == txnTime + 600 sec, trigger the chaincode function to transfer Marbles again but as a chaincode to chaincode invocation.  I have not tried invoking the same function with in itself. Might be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to automate a timed transaction from within the chaincode and it would be bad practice to try handle it there. If you try to create a timestamp from within the chaincode, it is guaranteed that all peers processing the transaction proposal will return different values as they do not all being processing the proposal at the same exact instance. Since the results sets will return non-deterministic, the transaction will always fail when it enters the validation phase. If you try to use `stub.GetTxTimestamp()` you will only be returning the timestamp that the *client itself* sent up, [as per the docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L338).

The best way to do this is with pure sdk code. After acquiring requisite transaction proposals and sending the transaction for ordering, listen for a transaction commitment event.

Upon receiving notification of transaction commitment, you can queue up another transaction to be sent endorsement and commitment 600 seconds later. The specifics of how will differ from sdk to sdk, but all sdk's support notification of transaction commitment.

Comment: That is not true. According to docs of `GetTxTimestamp()`: GetTxTimestamp returns the timestamp when the transaction was created. This is taken from the transaction ChannelHeader, therefore it will indicate the client's timestamp, and will have the same value across all endorsers.